# Android emulator gives error 0x501

Tags: android, android-studio, android-emulator

I'm using Android studio 1.1.0 and recently tried to create an virtual device/emulator using the Android virtual device manager.But, as soon as I run the device, the device opens up with a blank black screen while in Studio, i get the error as shown below.
I have also installed API 21 system images and also tried changing the device type in the emulator. None helped sadly.
How can I fix this?

Error log:

```
../../sdk/emulator/opengl//host/libs/Translator/GLES_V2//GLESv2Imp.cpp:glAttachShader:156 error 0x501
../../sdk/emulator/opengl//host/libs/Translator/GLES_V2//GLESv2Imp.cpp:glAttachShader:156 error 0x501
../../sdk/emulator/opengl//host/libs/Translator/GLES_V2//GLESv2Imp.cpp:glDetachShader:559 error 0x501
../../sdk/emulator/opengl//host/libs/Translator/GLES_V2//GLESv2Imp.cpp:glDetachShader:559 error 0x501
../../sdk/emulator/opengl//host/libs/Translator/GLES_V2//GLESv2Imp.cpp:glShaderSource:1760 error 0x501
../../sdk/emulator/opengl//host/libs/Translator/GLES_V2//GLESv2Imp.cpp:glCompileShader:355 error 0x501
../../sdk/emulator/opengl//host/libs/Translator/GLES_V2//GLESv2Imp.cpp:glGetShaderiv:1273 error 0x501
../../sdk/emulator/opengl//host/libs/Translator/GLES_V2//GLESv2Imp.cpp:glGetShaderInfoLog:1296 error 0x501
Error accepting connection, aborting
```

Answer (score 0):

make sure you have every intel atom in packages installed for your API level! then it should work, fixed it for me at least :)

Comment: I have installed ARM EABI v7a system image but not the atom ones. I have anyways reverted back to Eclipse IDE from Studio. Thanks for the suggestion

Comment: I recommend you to use Android Studio if you're professional developer. :)